# Extract SQL Query with Python

Tags: python, sql

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Date_B]
      ,[A]
      ,[B]
FROM [ZEN].[dbo].[test]
where ([Date] between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31') 
and ([Time] between '10:00:00' and '12:30:00') 
and (((DATEDIFF (day, Date, Date_B) < 20)
and (DATEDIFF (day, Date, Date_B) > 5)
and ([A] = 'X'))
or ([B] = 'Y'))
```

Is it possible to extract this Query (SQL 2017) with Python?

I´ve tried with `pyodbc`, but my code doesn´t work.

```
import pyodbc 
a = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=server_name;"
                      "Database=ZEN;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = a.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT [Date] ,[Time] ,[Date_B] ,[A] ,[B] FROM ZEN  where ([Date] between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31' and ([Time] between '10:00:00' and '12:30:00') and (((DATEDIFF (day, Date, Date_B) < 20) and (DATEDIFF (day, Date, Date_B) > 5) and ([A] = 'X')) or ([B] = 'Y')))')
```

Comment: Show your code which doesn't work

Comment: Show us the stack trace.